# Is it possible to take the parameter value dynamically from the database in MSSQL stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I want to display all the properties of the vehicle when I scanned it's bar code by bar code scanner. The entry of each and every vehicle's bar code is stored in Microsoft SQL database. Is it possible to write procedure regarding this? If yes, then give me some ideas.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[vq_proc]
@Vehicle_id varchar(50),
@L1_Employee varchar(50) output,
@L2_Employee varchar(50) output,
@L3_Employee varchar(50) output,
@L4_Employee varchar(50) output,
@R1_Employee varchar(50) output,
@R2_Employee varchar(50) output,
@R3_Employee varchar(50) output,
@AF_Date varchar(50) output,
@AF_Time varchar(50) output,
@LWR varchar(50) output,
@Noise varchar(50) output,
@LWL varchar(50) output,
@Elec varchar(50) output

AS
BEGIN

  --L1 employee
  Select @L1_Employee= emp.Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='L1' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id
  --L2
  Select @L2_Employee= emp.Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='L2' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id
  --L3
  Select @L3_Employee= emp.Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='L3' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id
  --L4
  Select @L4_Employee= emp.Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='L4' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id

  --R1
  select @R1_Employee= emp.Employee_name from log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='R1' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id
  --R2
   select @R2_Employee= emp.Employee_name from log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='R2' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id
  --R3
  Select @R3_Employee= Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='R3' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id

  --Aq
  Select @AF_Date= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),timestamp,101),@AF_Time= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),timestamp,108)/*, */ FROM log_Station s1 where  @Vehicle_id= s1.Vehicle_id/*HVQ_Vehicle*/ 
  --LW &R
  Select @LWR= Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='LW' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id
  --Noise
  Select @Noise= Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='Noise' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id
  --LW & L
  Select @LWL= Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='LW' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id  and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id
  --Elc
  Select @Elec= Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='Elc' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id  and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id


SELECT  @L1_Employee as N'@L1_Employee',
        @L2_Employee as N'@L2_Employee',
        @L3_Employee as N'@L3_Employee',
        @L4_Employee as N'@L4_Employee',
        @R1_Employee as N'@R1_Employee',
        @R2_Employee as N'@R2_Employee',
        @R3_Employee as N'@R3_Employee',
        @AF_Date as N'@AF_Date',
        @AF_Time as N'@AF_Time',
        @LWR as N'@LWR',
        @Noise as N'@Noise',
        @LWL as N'@LWL',
        @Elec as N'@Elec'

END
```

When I scanned the bar code the vehicle ID should be displayed in the frame number field. And I need to write stored procedure to pull out the vehicle ID from the database. [image: This is what I am trying to write the procedure for]

Comment: yes, you have to pass the vehicle id to procedure and procedure will return the cursor that will have the properties of that vehicle.

Comment: @Pirate, Thank you Sir. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: This is sqlserver code. Are you trying to convert to mysql or is the question incorrectly tagged?

Comment: @P.Salmon, Incorrectly tagged.

Comment: For that you would need an input of a barcode and an output dataset containing the car properties. That's just a `select` statement. I don't know what the stored proc you posted is meant to do. What have you actually tried. Have you written any code? What are you using to capture the barcode value?

Comment: Seems to me that you need a PIVOT function to correctly select all your values for a particular vehicle ID with just 1 select (don't need output parameters). Many examples here in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I am not clear on your data - but I prepared your stored procedure.  Your Select lines are all pulling employee name, if that is not correct, then you can adjust what is done here:

Tables:

```
Create Table log_station
(
Employee_id varchar(10),
Vehicle_id varchar(50),
station_code varchar(10)

)
Insert Into log_station Values
('x','1','L1'),
('x','1','L2'),
('x','1','L3'),
('x','1','L4'),
('y','1','R1'),
('y','1','R2'),
('y','1','R3'),
('x','1','LWR'),
('x','1','Noise'),
('x','1','LWL'),
('x','1','Elec')

Create Table HVQ_Employee
(
Employee_id varchar(10),
employee_name varchar(50)
)
Insert Into  HVQ_Employee Values
('x','Bill Smith'),
('y','Mary Jones')
```

Stored Procedure: some adjustments were made to your proc for GetDate and a few selection criteria seemed to have mis-spellings

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Alter  PROCEDURE [dbo].[vq_proc]
@Vehicle_id varchar(50),
@L1_Employee varchar(50) output,
@L2_Employee varchar(50) output,
@L3_Employee varchar(50) output,
@L4_Employee varchar(50) output,
@R1_Employee varchar(50) output,
@R2_Employee varchar(50) output,
@R3_Employee varchar(50) output,
@AF_Date varchar(50) output,
@AF_Time varchar(50) output,
@LWR varchar(50) output,
@Noise varchar(50) output,
@LWL varchar(50) output,
@Elec varchar(50) output

AS
BEGIN

  --L1 employee
  Select @L1_Employee= emp.Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='L1' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id
  --L2
  Select @L2_Employee= emp.Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='L2' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id
  --L3
  Select @L3_Employee= emp.Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='L3' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id
  --L4
  Select @L4_Employee= emp.Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='L4' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id

  --R1
  select @R1_Employee= emp.Employee_name from log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='R1' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id
  --R2
   select @R2_Employee= emp.Employee_name from log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='R2' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id
  --R3
  Select @R3_Employee= Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='R3' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id

  --Aq
  Select @AF_Date= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GetDate(),101),@AF_Time= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GetDate(),108)/*, */ FROM log_Station s1 where  @Vehicle_id= s1.Vehicle_id/*HVQ_Vehicle*/ 
  --LW &R
  Select @LWR= Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='LWR' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id
  --Noise
  Select @Noise= Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='Noise' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id
  --LW & L
  Select @LWL= Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='LWL' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id  and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id
  --Elc
  Select @Elec= Employee_name From log_Station s1,HVQ_Employee emp where s1.station_code='Elec' and s1.Employee_id=emp.Employee_id  and s1.Vehicle_id= @Vehicle_id

/*
SELECT  @L1_Employee as N'@L1_Employee',
        @L2_Employee as N'@L2_Employee',
        @L3_Employee as N'@L3_Employee',
        @L4_Employee as N'@L4_Employee',
        @R1_Employee as N'@R1_Employee',
        @R2_Employee as N'@R2_Employee',
        @R3_Employee as N'@R3_Employee',
        @AF_Date as N'@AF_Date',
        @AF_Time as N'@AF_Time',
        @LWR as N'@LWR',
        @Noise as N'@Noise',
        @LWL as N'@LWL',
        @Elec as N'@Elec'
*/
END
```

Execute:

```
Declare @Vehicle_id varchar(50)
Declare @L1_Employee varchar(50)
Declare @L2_Employee varchar(50)
Declare @L3_Employee varchar(50)
Declare @L4_Employee varchar(50)
Declare @R1_Employee varchar(50)
Declare @R2_Employee varchar(50)
Declare @R3_Employee varchar(50)
Declare @AF_Date varchar(50)
Declare @AF_Time varchar(50)
Declare @LWR varchar(50)
Declare @Noise varchar(50)
Declare @LWL varchar(50) 
Declare @Elec varchar(50)

Set @Vehicle_id = '1'

Exec vq_proc @vehicle_id,
@L1_Employee Output,
@L2_Employee Output, 
@L3_Employee Output, 
@L4_Employee Output, 
@R1_Employee Output, 
@R2_Employee Output, 
@R3_Employee Output,
@AF_Date Output,
@AF_Time Output, 
@LWR Output, 
@Noise Output, 
@LWL Output, 
@Elec Output 

SELECT  @vehicle_id As N'@vehicle_id',
        @L1_Employee as N'@L1_Employee',
        @L2_Employee as N'@L2_Employee',
        @L3_Employee as N'@L3_Employee',
        @L4_Employee as N'@L4_Employee',
        @R1_Employee as N'@R1_Employee',
        @R2_Employee as N'@R2_Employee',
        @R3_Employee as N'@R3_Employee',
        @AF_Date as N'@AF_Date',
        @AF_Time as N'@AF_Time',
        @LWR as N'@LWR',
        @Noise as N'@Noise',
        @LWL as N'@LWL',
        @Elec as N'@Elec'
```

Result:

```
@vehicle_id @L1_Employee    @L2_Employee    @L3_Employee    @L4_Employee    @R1_Employee    @R2_Employee    @R3_Employee    @AF_Date    @AF_Time    @LWR        @Noise      @LWL        @Elec
1           Bill Smith      Bill Smith      Bill Smith      Bill Smith      Mary Jones      Mary Jones      Mary Jones      12/28/2018  08:35:36    Bill Smith  Bill Smith  Bill Smith  Bill Smith
```